# pyinstaller: "No such file or directory" but program keeps executing

Tags: python, machine-learning, pycharm, pyinstaller, filenotfoundexception

I am using Pyinstaller on Mac. I was able to create an executable by running `pyinstaller --onefile --paths /Users/wnba/PycharmProjects/a2_part3/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages gp.py` But when I run the created file `gp`, it has a strange error says `[3723] Failed to execute script gp
exitTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "gp.py", line 56, in <module>
  File "gp.py", line 12, in read_file
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '-B'`

My gp.py around line 12 looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
import sys
import re
import gplearn
from gplearn.genetic import SymbolicClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
def read_file(path):
    with open(path, 'r') as sourcefile: # this is line 12 
    sourcelines = sourcefile.read()
```

The way I parse args is:

```
read_file(sys.argv[1])
```

Could you please help to point out what was wrong? Many thanks

Comment: The variable path has contents '-B' which is probably an option, not a file path. You probably parsed the arguments wrong. The problem is when you try to open(path) not run gp.py

Comment: I edited the question with the way I parsed the argument. I run it by using the command gp.py inputfile . Could you help shed light on what could be wrong here? The program keeps running with these errors coming up at the same time. I have no clue what's wrong..